# Spring 3.1 REST @PathVariable dependencies

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I'm creating a **RESTful API** with **Spring MVC 3.1**.  I have a unique database per `Project`, so my REST urls for `Collection` must include `Project` so i know what database to connect to.

I've used `registerCustomEditor` in `@InitBinder` to auto-magically resolve `@PathVariable Project project` *(awesome!)*.

But now i'm getting greedy and I want to automatically resolve `@PathVariable Collection collection` instead of doing the same thing over and over in each action in this controller. The problem is that `Collection` depends on `Project` being resolved.  So how do I set it up with this dependency?

Thanks for any help!!

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/project/{project}/collection", produces = {"application/json", "application/xml"})
public class CollectionController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CollectionController.class);  

    @Autowired protected ProjectRepository projectRepository;
    @Autowired protected CollectionService collectionService;
    @Autowired protected PermissionService permissionService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<CollectionResponse> query(@ActiveAccount Account account, @PathVariable Project project) {

        if (!permissionService.hasProjectAccess(account, project)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
        }

        CollectionRepository collectionRepository = collectionService.getCollectionRepository(project);
        List<Collection> collections = collectionRepository.findByProjectId(project.getId());

        List<CollectionResponse> response = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Collection collection : collections) {
            response.add(new CollectionResponse(collection));
        }

        return response;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{collection}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody CollectionResponse get(@ActiveAccount Account account, @PathVariable Project project, @PathVariable String collection) {

        if (!permissionService.hasProjectAccess(account, project)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException("Access Denied");
        }

        CollectionRepository collectionRepository = collectionService.getCollectionRepository(project);

        return new CollectionResponse(collectionRepository.findOne(collection));
    }

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Project.class, new PropertyEditorSupport() {

            @Override
            public String getAsText() {
                return ((Project) this.getValue()).getId();
            }

            @Override
            public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
                setValue(projectRepository.findOne(text));
            }
        });
    }   

}
```

Comment: To resolve the collection, you require the project, so essentially these things have to happen in two separate steps. I don't see how you could do it without doing something strange, like adding the project as stateful data somewhere for the collection's CustomEditor to use (bad idea). I think you're best off trying to restrain your greed here!

Comment: I think you could be right.  Moving all of that logic to the service layer (including calls to permissionService) would make things simpler.  Sometimes it's just easier to go with the flow :)